# I don't have a Mac. Someone tested my website on a Mac and the Google Maps' Javascript is not working. How do I test it?

Tags: cross-browser, safari, mac

How do I test if a website works on an old Mac without owning a Mac? Are there emulates. Does Safari work the same on both XP and a Mac? On the PC the website works on ie 7-9, FireFox, Opera, Safari, and Chrome. It works on a very old iPhone too but not a five year old Mac. Here is a screen shot of I just got from Browser Shots on Safari 4.0 which is exactly how it's supposed to look.

[image]

Comment: "Does Safari work the same on both XP and a Mac" I think they do…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a virtual machine, like Virtualbox, VMware, etc. but you would need to have a license of Mac OS to test it with.

Safari, however, should look the same on all operating systems it runs on (in theory), and that seems like a pretty big flaw, so I would assume that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I kept thinking about what might be wrong and realized the answer. The problem is that the mac has a small screen and categories listed on the page hide the map so the person had no idea what I was talking about having a map show. For the past day I've been walking my friends on their computers through the website in about 1 minute. That's enough instruction to understand how to use it as an application. However, anybody just looking at will not understand what it is or why it's useful. Basically, I called my friend back and said scroll down. I have a lot of work to do on it still.